# Issue with Next.js 13 and User Context not working outside _app.tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

I'm using Next.js 13 and using user context, but it doesn't work outside _app.tsx. Why is that?

**src>context>UserPositionContext.tsx**

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const UserPositionContext = createContext({});

export const useUserPosition = () => {
  return useContext(UserPositionContext);
};

export const UserPositionProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [userPosition, setUserPosition] = useState(0);
  return <UserPositionContext.Provider value={{ userPosition, setUserPosition }}>{children}</UserPositionContext.Provider>;
};

export default UserPositionProvider;
```

***src>pages>_app.tsx useContext can read if i declare here**

```
import { ThemeProvider, DefaultTheme } from "styled-components";
import UserPositionProvider from "../context/UserPositionContext";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
return (
  <\>
    <UserPositionProvider\>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}\>
        <Component {...pageProps} /\>
      </ThemeProvider\>
    </UserPositionProvider\>
  </\>
);
}
```

***src>pages>user.tsx useContext cannot read if I declare here**

```
import UserComponent from "@/components/organism/UserNav";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import UserPositionProvider from "../context/UserPositionContext";

type Props = {};

const User = ({}: Props) =\> {
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  const router = useRouter();
  router.push("/user/profile");
}
return (
  <UserPositionProvider\>
    <UserComponent /\>
  </UserPositionProvider\>
);
};

export default User;
```

I have tried to test it with console.log, and if I put the provider in user.tsx file the error message "setUserPosition" is not defined. But if I put it back in _app.tsx it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The component exported in `_app.tsx` is a wrapper around all your pages. When you wrap the children in `_app.tsx` using your `UserPositionProvider`, the context will be a wrapper around every components rendered in your pages.
So it can be accessed from any of child components of those pages.

But if you import it in your `user` page and initialize it only there, you can only access it from child components of that page.
So you won't be able to access its properties from a component that is not a child of the `user` page component if you use the Context's provider only in the user component.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'use client' at the top and it will work for sure.

I was stuck in this for the past 4 hours and weirdly this is the only thing that worked.